# ios Static Library - how obfuscate directly?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, unity-game-engine, obfuscation

I have an application Unity that uses the iOS static library. Then this application Unity is build in XCode. I found several utilities that allow you to obfuscate the library in the application. for example this - [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename).

I carefully read their documentation "Obfuscate Static Libraries", but at the time of building, the iOS static library are already "hidden in the root" of the Unity app, and XCode cannot obfuscate this.

So I need to first obfuscate the library and then add it to the application. or is it not possible?

Comment: This sounds weird... why? static library is built in into binary of your your app. Do you obfuscate your app binary as well? From what?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You have an application that uses a static library provided by iOS (Apple) or one that you have source code for?  You want to obfuscate the library to prevent what?  Reverse engineering, exposure of keys, or what?

Comment: I want to protect the library from  Reverse engineering

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of the documentation `PPiOS-Rename` stays an external tool, just the files `*.plist` can be added into the releases, for being able to use the tool on the compiled releases.
I might be completely wrong about it, especially as without iOS I can't test it, but I'd check if my statement is right and if you can omit the step to include the library in your compiled releases.

About handling of `*.plist` files, follow the instructions on the linked page, I'm not sure if you have one or more in the end. As it doesn't seem relevant to the core of your question, I never verified it deeper.